# ZF2 - same view file for multiple actions in a Controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Im using ZF2 and I need to render same view (html page) in both add and edit actions. Is there a way to do it in ZF2 ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your controller, you can set the view script that will be rendered:

```
function someAction()
{
    $result = new ViewModel();
    $result->setTemplate('somemodule/somecontroller/arbitraryscript');

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Please keep in mind to return the ViewModel so the front can catch it. Add "return $result;" to the end.

Answer (score 4):

And if you want to set one template for all Actions just rewrite your construtor methode:

```
<?php
namespace MyModel\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    /**
     * @var ViewModel
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $viewModel;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->viewModel = new ViewModel();
        $this->viewModel->setTemplate('MyModel/index/default.phtml');
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->viewModel->setVariables(array(
            'message' => 'Hello indexAction()'
        ));
        return $this->viewModel;
    }

    public function otherAction()
    {
        return $this->viewModel->setVariables(array(
            'message' => 'Hello otherAction()'
        ));
    }
}
```